# How to insert data in two tables at the database at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I work using SQL Server. I have 2 tables, `Animal` and `Cat`. When I add a new cat to the database, I want to update both tables. I should add the cat to the `Animal` table first, so that I can add the `animal_Id` to the `Cat` table afterwards.

Is there a way to add the record at two tables at the same time? If there isn't, what is the best way to do it?

I just want an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a [transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), both inserts will be done, at least logically, "at the same time".

That means that no other query, done from outside of the transaction, can see the base "between the inserts". And if there is a failure between both inserts (and no effective commit), the final state will ignore first insert.

In order to get the id of a row just added in your session, use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).

Comment: But how can I know the id in which the record was added with at the first table ?

Comment: You probably want SELECT [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)()

Answer (score 3):

You can't use INSERT against two tables in one statement.

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [A](...) VALUES(...);
INSERT INTO [B](...) VALUES(...);

COMMIT TRANSACTION
SET XACT_ABORT OFF
```

The transaction is to make sure it is everything or nothing is committed. The XACT_ABORT ensures that if one fails with an error (therefore `COMMIT TRANSACTION` will not fire), the transaction will be forced to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use transaction here. For example (if you know the Id of new row beforehand):

```
DECLARE @CAT TABLE(id int, name varchar(50));
DECLARE @ANIMAL TABLE(id int);
DECLARE @anmalId INT = 1;

BEGIN TRAN 
 INSERT INTO @ANIMAL VALUES(@anmalId);
 INSERT INTO @CAT VALUES(@anmalId, 'Kitty');
COMMIT TRAN

SELECT * FROM @CAT;
SELECT * FROM @ANIMAL;
```

You can use @@identity in case of auto increments.

Answer (score 0):

Use triggers. That is the best way

Answer (score -2):

how about using trigger while insertion to one table??